# Make an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am very beginner in Ruby and probably the question is too easy but well, I've already spent some time on it and couldn't find a solution.
My Ruby script takes a number (ex `10`) and a name (ex `Vincent`). What I want is to make an array looking like

```
Vincent0
Vincent1.. 
Vincent9
```

I can't figure a way to make it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def arrayfy(string, number)
  arr = []
  0.upto(number-1) do |i|
    arr << "#{string}#{i}"
  end
  return arr
end
```

Update: To add these as variables to the class

```
class Foo
  def arrayfy(string, number)
    0.upto(number-1) do |i|
      var_string = "@#{string}#{i}"
      var_symbol = var_string.to_sym
      self.instance_variable_set(var_symbol, "")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Perfect and fast answer.

Comment: Ok and how can I form a variable out of the name + number like name = Vincent1? I will surely accept in 4 min.

Comment: @sparkymat..just a suggestion..you can use `(0...number)` or `number.times` instead of `0.upto(number-1)`

Comment: @sparkymat..also you can use `Enumerable#map` function to create array in the first function like this `def arrayfy(string, number); arr = (0...number).map { |i| "#{string}#{i}" }; arr; end`

Comment: @rubyprince: Thank you! I knew there was a way to do this, but just couldn't remember how.

Comment: You don't need `return` at the end of the first `arrayfy`.

Comment: I don't believe its a good practice to rely on an implicit return. I have seen instances in big projects, where one person would expect an implicit return and someone else might add someone logic later which breaks the return. Implicit return is fine for short code, but requires a lot of discipline for larger project. Personally, I prefer sticking to explicit returns.

Answer (score 3):

Using `Array.new` with a block ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000209)):

```
def create_array(count, name)
  Array.new(10) { |i| "#{name}#{i} }
end
```

Using `Enumerable#reduce` ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001495)):

```
def create_array(count, name)
  (0...count).reduce([]) { |m,i| m << "#{name}#{i}" }
end
```

Or using `Enumerable#each_with_object` ([docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M001516)):

```
def create_array(count, name)
  (0...count).each_with_object([]) { |i,a| a << "#{name}#{i}" }
end
```

Using it:

```
# Using the array (assigning to variables)
array = create_array(10, 'Vincent') # => ['Vincent0', 'Vincent1', 'Vincent2' ...]
name  = array[1]                    # => 'Vincent1'
```

Comment: You could use `each_with_object` rather than `reduce`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Array.new(10) {|i| "Vincent#{i}"}
```

gives you

```
["Vincent0", "Vincent1", "Vincent2", "Vincent3", "Vincent4", "Vincent5", 
"Vincent6", "Vincent7", "Vincent8", "Vincent9"]
```

The documentation for Array is available at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html (googling for Array RDoc will give you the URL).

The bit in the braces (`{|i| "Vincent#{i}"}`) is called a block. You'll definitely want to learn about them.

Comment: I didnt know of this iniitialization of an array..I used to go with `Enumerable#map` for these cases..cool..thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, a solution in a more functional style:

```
>> def arrayify(str, n)
..   ([str] * n).zip(0...n).map(&:join)
..   end 
#=> nil
>> arrayify('Vincent', 10) 
#=> ["Vincent0", "Vincent1", "Vincent2", "Vincent3", "Vincent4", "Vincent5", "Vincent6", "Vincent7", "Vincent8", "Vincent9"]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, were you aware of the `Array.new(size) {|index| block}` form?

Comment: @Andrew: By reading my posts here I'm quite sure that you know the answer to that is yes. Just sometimes when questions are already accepted — as this one was — I try and add "original" or "interesting" solutions. I think it's mostly a habit acquired when teaching at RubyLearning, since it's a good way to direct peoples attention at new methods etc.

Comment: I can tell you have a pretty high reputation, but sometimes experienced users think they don't have to consult the RDocs. That's what I thought was the case here. There's nothing stopping you from suggesting multiple approaches in a question

Answer (score 0):

```
def array_maker(number, string)
  result = []
  for i in 0..number do
    result << "#{string}#{i}"
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: This is completely off the original question.

Comment: well you changed it from the time I commented, or something is completely off in stack overflow, this was array = ["one", "two", "three"]

Comment: I changed it BEFORE you commented it

Comment: btw, its still would be for i in 0..number-1 do, its still off by 1.

Comment: It doesn't metter, I just wanted to give the idea of solution

Comment: @daniel: S.O. allows the poster to edit the answer upto some X duration and does not show the "edited <time> ago" link unless the answer is edited after that X duration has passed. Not sure what the X value is though (could even be X number of edits instead of a duration).